# TexField in Scientific Workplace

Tags: scientific-workplace

I am trying to put a page number on a specific page and then an author name centered on that same page. I am using Scientific Workplace and inserted a TexField to do this. I tried `\begin{center}Author\end{center}` and `\begin{flushleft}page number\end{flushleft}`. It works, except that it puts Author on a new line. So then I tried also doing `\nolinebreak`, but then it tells me that there is no line break to end. I have tried different orders for the TexFields, putting all of the commands in on TexField, etc., but nothing works. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you give

```
\begin{center}\hfill Author\hfill\llap{55}\end{center}
```

a try? Of course, be sure to replace `55` with whatever number is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll give that a try.

Comment: Thank you-that works to get the page number at the upper right. I'm trying to figure out how to get the page number at the upper left. How would that be done ? I'm assuming llap would be replaced by something else, but I don't know what.

Comment: @AlanHorwitz - How about `\begin{center}56\hfill Author\hfill\phantom{56}\end{center}`.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you again.